# How to use deleteAll() function inside a loop in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i am trying to truncate a selected models from my application using [deleteAll()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#deleteAll()-detail)

my controller:

there are a lot of models but i didn't include them for maintain as short.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Marks;
use app\models\ActivityHistory;
use app\models\Attendance;
use app\models\Students;
public function actionTruncate(){

    $models = array("Marks","ActivityHistory","Attendance","Students");

    foreach($models as $key=>$model){
        $model::deleteAll();
    }
   exit;
}
```

this getting error that

> Class 'Marks' not found

when i run individual query like `Marks::deleteAll();` it works.
how to solve this in loop?
and suggest me a good way to do this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$models = [Marks::class, ActivityHistory::class, Attendance::class, Students::class];

foreach ($models as $model) {
     $model::deleteAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `use` statement only works for classes referenced directly. The use statement is resolved by preprocessor. It has no way to know if `"Marks"` string is meant to reference class or if it has some other meaning. If you want to use dynamic name of class you have to use fully qualified name of class.

The following ways of setting class names should work:

```php
$models = array(
    //this way should always work
    "\app\models\Marks",
    "app\models\ActivityHistory",
    // ::class magic constant added in php 5.5
    Attendance::class,
    // deprecated
    Students::className(),
);
```

The `className()` method is deprecated and if you are using php 5.5 or newer you should use `::class` constant instead. The method is still around for backward compatibility.